# Long execution time on simple C++ 'Hello World' program

Tags: c++, performance, g++, execution-time

A basic (and maybe stupid) question:

I just started learning C++ and as every first step in a new programming language I wrote a program to print out "Hello World":

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For this I use the `g++` compiler and the compilation finished quickly.
However the execution time is very long (about 26 seconds according to my IDE).

Compile command I used (if it should be relevant): `g++ main.cpp -o main`

I looked up another guy executing the exact same code with (as far as I know) the exactly same conditions and it took him about 0.05 seconds (according to the output print of his IDE).

I'm pretty sure that something similar to this was already asked a lot of times but I couldn't find any useful information regarding this in about 2 hours of research (maybe looked at the wrong places?) so I think it's justified to ask.

Any information, an optimization or just some suggestions on where to search, is appreciated.

-VoroX

Comment: Which OS was the test platform? What IDE?

Comment: Have you tried running the program outside of your IDE? My first hunch is that your IDE is performing some pre-run setup task very slowly and wrongly including it in the timing of the command, or that it's causing some sort of delay with actually reading the "Hello world" from the program and presenting it to you, which can cause the program itself to delay exiting.

Comment: What IDE are you using? How do you run the program from inside the IDE?

Comment: Likely to be your antivirus not allowing your program to run until its been scanned

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Windows 10, Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Then @AlanBirtles is right

Comment: @AlanBirtles Tested this already, whitelisted the compiler, the IDE and my program, didn't really change anything

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- Yes I ran it both in the IDE but also in the default console, didn't really change anything

Comment: Did you try to close your antivirus software temporally?

Comment: @VoroX whitelisting won't help because each compilation will create a different binary. AV software generally is not intelligent to recognize the presence of a compiler and developing information in an executable. Disable your AV entirely (or even better, get rid of it. It's useless anyway).

Comment: Well, nevermind, apparently the antivirus WAS the problem, I just whitelisted it as a process however it needed to be listed under an special section for files to ignore, thanks to all

Comment: most antivirus programs allow you to specify exceptions e.g. do not scan anything in folder XYZ, maybe that is something you should look into.

Comment: @AndersK I did already, thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the antivirus really was the problem, even thou I whitelisted my program, anyway if anyone else has a similar issue, and whilelisting won't help, try to disable your antivirus temporarily.

Thanks to Alan Birtles :)